# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los ceros de una caja de texto en otra caja de texto como resultado? C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una aplicación en la que me gustaría mostrar los ceros en el resultado de la suma de la cadena string de varias cajas de texto. Se les agradece de antemano.

Aquí les muestro el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo aplicado al botón:

```
Negocio = Convert.ToByte(this.textBoxNegocio.Text);
Emision = Convert.ToByte(this.textBoxEmision.Text);
Impresion = Convert.ToByte(this.textBoxImpresion.Text);
Comprobante = Convert.ToByte(this.comboBoxComprobante.Text);

textBoxNCF.Text = Convert.ToString(comboBoxSerie.Text) + Negocio.ToString() + Emision.ToString() + Impresion.ToString() + Comprobante.ToString();
```

Comment: Si los conviertes a Byte (o a otro formato numérico) te va a quitar los 0 de delante

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: La pregunta aca, es porque los convertis a byte para luego volver a convertilos a string. Esto se debe a alguna logica en particular? porque no parece estar bien.

Comment: @gbianchi te ha dado la clave. Para que conviertes a byte el contenido de los textbox, si luego lo vuelves a pasar a string?. En esa conversión es donde estas perdiendo los ceros

Comment: Yo di por sentado que lo necesita en byte pq hace operaciones con ellos en otro lado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ponen [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros) tienes varias formas de dar formato a un número cuando lo pasas a string, pero tienes que decirle de antemano hasta cuantos ceros quieres que te ponga:

Yo te recomiento una de estas dos

```
Impresion.ToString("0000");
Impresion.ToString("D4");
```

Por ejemplo si el valor que pusieras fuera 01 te mostraria 0001 si el valor fuera 223 pondria 0223

Comment: Creo que no has entendido la pregunta. El problema del op es que quiere concatenar unos string, pero al convertirles primero a byte esta perdiendo los ceros

Comment: la respuesta esta bien, pero la pregunta no tiene sentido, porque esta perdiendo a proposito esos ceros.

Comment: si hace Convert.ToString(comboBoxSerie.Text) + Negocio.ToString("D3") + Emision.ToString("D3"), no perdera los 0 no? ¿No es eso lo que quiere?

Comment: Y si en negocio meten en el textbox `000000002` ? Como sabes cuantos ceros ha metido?

Comment: Con eso estas obligando a la salida a tener x ceros delante, sin embargo el # puede variar puede ser 01, 002, y ahi ya no funcionaría eso.

Comment: Para el control de entrada tengo lo siguiente: Regex RxSerie = new Regex("^[A-Z]{1}");
                Regex RxNegocio = new Regex("^[0-9]{2}");
                Regex RxEmision = new Regex("^[0-9]{3}");
                Regex RxImpresion = new Regex("^[0-9]{3}");

Comment: @Kodake en ese caso, ya que sabes exactamente el numero de digitos de cada textbox, puede servirte esta respuesta. Pero simplemente eliminando el `Convert.ToByte` en todas las asignaciones, tambien te funcionará

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no estas usando la conversión a byte, ya que no haces ninguna operación matemática con esos datos. Y al final solo sumas su valor para agregarlo a una string, te recomiendo que hagas lo siguiente:

Como los 3 campos de tipo texto que vi sus valores son números puedes validar en caso que desees que no entren letras para que tu resultado no sea indeseado. Si no importa el tipo de dato que entres puedes obviar este paso.

Agrega este using al comienzo de tu archivo

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Crea esta función y asignsela al evento onKeyPress de los 3 campos de textos: División de Negocio, Punto de Emisión y Area de Impresión.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if(!Regex.Match(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "^\\d$").Success &&
            e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back && e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Delete)
        {
            e.KeyChar = (char)0;
        }
    }
```

Con esto solo podran entrar números y por supuesto borrar el texto con las teclas de backspace y delete respectivamente.

Y ya luego reemplazarías las converciones a byte por esta línea

```
textBoxNCF.Text = comboBoxSerie.Text + textBoxNegocio.Text + textBoxEmision.Text + textBoxImpresion.Text + comboBoxComprobante.Text;
```

Comment: Esto es matar mosquitos con cañones.. si el problema es puramente la conversion innecesaria!

Comment: Arriba indique que si el no queria validarlo pasara al último paso donde remuevo la conversión innecesario igual no esta de más tu comentario. ;P

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas hacer es **concatenar** los strings en varias Cajas de Texto, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
textBoxNCF.Text = Convert.ToString(comboBoxSerie.Text) + this.textBoxNegocio.Text + this.textBoxEmision.Text + this.textBoxImpresion.Text + this.comboBoxComprobante.Text;
```

Pero si lo que deseas hacer es **sumar** las cadenas de texto y mostrar los ceros, puedes hacer algo asi:

```
// Te quedas con la mayor longitud
int max = Math.Max(this.textBoxNegocio.Text.Lenght, Math.Max(this.textBoxEmision.Text.Lenght, Math.Max(this.textBoxImpresion.Text.Lenght, this.comboBoxComprobante.Text.Lenght));

// Conviertes a int (o lo que desees) y sumas
int negocio = int.Parse(this.textBoxNegocio.Text);
int emision = int.Parse(this.textBoxEmision.Text);
int impresion = int.Parse(this.textBoxImpresion.Text);
int comprobante = int.Parse(this.comboBoxComprobante.Text);

int sumaTotal = negocio + emision + impresion + comprobante;

// Finalmente
string result = sumaTotal;
for(int i = sumaTotal.ToString().Lenght; i < max; i++)
{
    result = "0" + result;
}

// Ya en result tienes la suma con ceros al principio
```